# Returning a Dictionary using LINQ for all items that satisfy two conditions

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database table setup as an entity in EF Core which looks like this:

| GUID | PartNumber | UploadStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 444 | 1 | 1 |
| 444 | 1 | 1 |
| 555 | 2 | 0 |
| 555 | 2 | 1 |

How can I return a `Dictionary<string, bool>` using LINQ for all GUIDs that have an `UploadStatus` of 1?

For example, the query should return the dict containing a key:

- value pair of 444: true when executed
- since 555 has one incomplete upload, 555: false should be returned

Comment: Something like `Items.GroupBy(e => e.GUID).Select(g => new {Guid = g.Key, AllUploadsSucceeded = g.All(e => e.UploadStatus == 1)}).ToDictionary(e => e.Guid, e => e.AllUploadsSucceeded);`

Comment: This worked perfectly once I switched the UploadStatus int to an enum. Thanks!

Comment: So you're probably in EF-core 2. Note that in later versions client-side evaluation was abandoned. As as consequence, `GroupBy` support got very limited and this case won't translate if `Items` is `IQueryable`.